Keep getting error message tying to run python in vscode on mac?
enter image description hereI really hope someone can help troubleshoot what is causing this issue. Keep getting
/bin/sh: python: command not found

Does anyone have any suggestions? I Saw some other people had the same issue but the workaround was installation via Home Brew, which didn't seem to help in my case.
I've tried uninstalling and re-installing Python3 multiple times and finally tried installing it via Home Brew. Everything seems ok, it is for sure the latest version installed on my Mac. But trying to run a simple print script in VScode and I keep getting this error message.

Maybe the correct command is python3, not just python?

I figured out is was actually a setting in the code runner extension causing the issue. By just adjusting the json. setting in the extension from python to python3, it resolved the issue.

You're most likely using the wrong interpreter path.

Use Command + P to open up the search bar


Then type > and select Python: select interpreter option.




Then select your interpreter


If for some reason you VScode didn't already detect your interpreter in your system you can input the path manually on the top option
Alternatively, the command can be python3 as opposed to just python
